# How to generally express the chewable parts of soup in English?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I often cook fruit or nuts or vegetables or meat with water and a bit sugar or salt to form a so-called soup.

And my little daughter just wants to eat the chewable parts not the water part of the soup.

**How to *generally* express the chewable parts of soup in English?**

For example "**she liked to eat nuts not water of soup**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:

- She only likes the solid bits [and not the liquid/water/broth]

A possible problem is that *solid* sounds a bit sterile, like a medical term ("she can't eat solid food").

You could also say:

- She only likes the chewy bits [like nuts and meat]

This is OK, but it is vaguer than *solid*. Also, nuts usually aren't chewy, in the way that e.g. tough lamb is.

You could also say:

- She only likes the chunky bits

This is also vague, but it has the advantage of making the soup sound tastier! (*Chunky* is sometimes associated with tasty soups or food in general.)

Comment: but when you cook nuts or tough lamb in hot water long enough, then you can chew them. You can't eat them if you can't chew them right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But be careful, *chewy* does not mean *chewable*. You are talking about chewability, I was talking about *chewiness* (which means you have to chew it alot before it breaks down). Maybe I shouldn't have used that word in my answer, it was misleading. Go with chunky!

Comment: We are talking about soup, not the physical properties of materials. Use *chewy* because it is well understood and describes the sensations rather than the precise physical realities.