# Do we say "The water of the soup is yummy"?

Tags: word-request

I know this is a bowl of soup

[image]

so, the soup has liquid, vegetables and meat.

If I have to say each component of the soup seperately.

Can I say the liquid "**water**"? and say the vegetables "**bits**"?

For example, "**I just want to eat the bits, I don't want the water**" or "**this water is yummy but the bits are tasteless**"

Comment: Relevant, but IMO not exhaustively answered: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/268157/how-to-generally-express-the-chewable-parts-of-soup-in-english

Comment: If you call it 'water', you are implying that it is tasteless! (NB _Yummy_ is informal and rather childish. _Delicious_ or _very good_ sound more adult.)

Comment: "The broth is amazing!"

Comment: Tom: You need to give credit for these pictures you post. They are copyrighted. How many times do we need to tell you this?

Comment: Related: [What is the very thick liquid called when we braise meat in coconut milk?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/320011/what-is-the-very-thick-liquid-called-when-we-braise-meat-in-coconut-milk)

Comment: "water" is a mistake here. Also, bear in mind that this is an Asian soup. Not something one would usually find in Western cuisine. Your picture shows an Asian vegetable soup made of vegetables in its own **broth**.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The liquid is **broth**.

There's not as much of a standard name for the bits; I think it might be *solids*, but in a conversation you're just as likely to hear "the uh, y'know, the floaty bits, not the broth." The best option is often to just say what's in the soup.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure [*broth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broth) works as well if the soup isn't a thin and clear one the way it is with just unthickened stock or bouillon. I'm thinking in particular of thicker soups like tomato soup, split pea soup, and New England clam [chowder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chowder); *broth* might not be optimal with those, but I have no better suggestion.

Comment: I think the meaning of ‘broth’ varies between regions.  Here in the UK it's usually a thick, starchy soup (e.g. [Scotch broth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_broth)); a thin soup (such as the liquid in the question) would be a consommé, bouillon, or stock.  (In either case, you could simply call it ‘liquid’.)

Comment: @gibbs The main place I've come across the term "bouillon" is "bouillon cubes", so ironically I associate it with concentrated broth.

Comment: I think a more generic word might be "liquid". for "cream of X" soups, it's presumably the cream.

Comment: For a bit of regional flavour (SWIDT?), here in the SE of England, if one wanted to refer to the individual components of a soup, the liquid component would usually be called the soup and the non-liquid components would be specifically named, so in the example of the OP's photograph the liquid would be the soup and the green bits the vegetables or just the beans. When the soup is thick enough for the whole dish to be known as "broth" it's "broth" and "vegetables" (or whatever ingredient is being discussed). I'd avoid calling anything solid floating in liquid as "solids", too...

Comment: @gidds I'm in the UK, and I'd call what is pictured vegetables in a broth before consommé or bouillon came to mind.  Certainly not a stock, since it is intended to be consumed direct.

Comment: @gidds: To my (English) ear, the liquid in OP’s picture is definitely the *broth* of the soup — broth can either mean a whole soup (either thick or thin), or the liquid part of a liquid-with-things-in-it soup.    Like JamesT, I think of *stock* as referring to an ingredient rather than a finished dish; *consommé* as narrower, just meaning specific kinds of thin soup, usually meat-based; and *bouillon* as a rough synonym for a stock (as an ingredient), or as a soup that consists primarily just of stock.

Comment: also from the UK (SE England), and I'd probably refer to the individual components here as "vegetables" and "soup" (although "soup" can of course also refer to the entire dish). "Liquid" is another option for the liquid portion, but I wouldn't consider "broth" wrong. I think younger speakers here tend to understand "broth" more in the American sense, whereas gidds is giving the more traditional British sense

Comment: One doesn't say the liquid of the soup is good. One says broth, which can be clear broth, such as this one. And that is AmE and BrE, by the way. Collins Dictionary British English: broth
in British English
(brɒθ IPA Pronunciation Guide)
NOUN
1. a soup made by boiling meat, fish, vegetables, etc, in water Same for AmE. This answer is **correct**. Doesn't anyone use a dictionary?

Comment: Disagreeing with Andy: also in the UK but I'm happy with the liquid- as distinct from the solid- being broth. "But I upped with 'is heels, and I smothered his squeals, in the scum of the boiling broth." Scum would only form on the surface of something relatively thin: if it were thick like Scotch Broth it would be barely distinguishable from the bulk and easily subducted by the disturbance of a falling body.

Comment: @tchrist But in the picture, it **is** a clear broth. For clam chowder etc. that is simply the soup. But here, the liquid is broth.

Answer (score 6):

I would say that the liquid part is the **soup** (as commented by Spratty on the other answer). This is made very unclear by the fact that the whole dish is also called soup. I might say **liquid** if I wanted to be less ambiguous. **Broth**, as suggested by the-baby-is-you, will always be understood clearly but not be considered correct in all circumstances (as the discussion under his answer shows).

**Bits** is a perfectly good word to use for the vegetables etc. It's very informal, though, and doesn't sound very flattering, e.g. "the soup was okay, but the bits were overcooked and mushy". If you wanted to compliment them specifically it would sound much better to name them, e.g. "I thought the vegetables were very good".

Comment: soup is the whole thing, the broth and the vegetables.

Comment: @Lambie, broth is the whole thing, both soup and vegetables.  Depends where in the world you are, I think!

Comment: @TobySpeight Too many cooks spoil the broth. :)

Comment: But are croutons bits? We're opening a canteen of worms here: a broth (or stock), lumpy bits cooked in it, an administration of croutons, a garnish of parsley and even- $deity preserve us- PARMESAN!!!

Comment: @TobySpeight Not necessarily at all. I just asked a friend in London and he says that would be broth, so would I [in the US]. So, there is no difference. Maybe we should ask Jamie Oliver.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of precision, one could call soup ***without the vegetable pieces*** (previously discarded) *vegetable* [**consommé**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consomm%C3%A9) or *beef, chicken  consommé* if the stock  was made with meat.

The simpler dish, **clear soup** –*[Klare Suppe](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Klare%20Suppe%22&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj_le7n0KCDAxVvmScCHSg8ABoQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=%22Klare%20Suppe%22&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIHCAAQgAQQEzIHCAAQgAQQEzIHCAAQgAQQEzIHCAAQgAQQEzIHCAAQgAQQEzIHCAAQgAQQEzIHCAAQgAQQEzIICAAQBxAeEBMyCAgAEAcQHhATMggIABAHEB4QEzoECCMQJzoGCAAQBxAeOgQIABAeOgYIABAeEBM6CAgAEAUQHhATUP4JWMgfYMwlaABwAHgAgAFWiAHzAZIBATOYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=FD2EZf-7BO-ynsEPqPiA0AE&bih=630&biw=1144)* in German–is sometimes mistakenly called consommé which uses egg whites to clarify the soup. Instead, clear soup is strained through a fine sieve or a muslin cloth to filter impurities and make it completely clear.

[image: a small bowl of Japanese clear soup with a few pieces of vegetables]
[Source](https://recipes.timesofindia.com/recipes/japanese-clear-soup/rs58357074.cms)

Comment: clear soup, as you say, and broth are basically the same thing and this simply does not answer the OP's question at all.